# The "Curvers" is missing from add object menu

Tags: object-mode

I saw on youtube, other people using 3.2 alpha, enabled new curves type in exprimental setting.
How it looks like:

[image]

Now its version 3.2.2, I cannot find the same setting under experimental. So the feature should be there, but:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that first image isn't from a beta version? - My 3.2.2 doesn't have the 'Curves' entry below 'Curve'  in the add menu. Even 3.4 alpha doesn't have a 'Curves' entry although it does have Empty Hair on the Curve submenu.

Comment: I agree with @JohnEason here, my 3.2.2 doesn't have it, my 3.3.0 beta and my 3.4.0 alpha neither. Who are those "other people"? Where did you see that and do they give any information what version they are using?

Comment: I just added some detail @JohnEason

Comment: Yes, in Blender 3.2 alpha this was a feaure in the *Experimental* section. But that was an Alpha (=development) version. Experimental options are often not the release versions or moved. In this case, it's no longer in 3.2.x. I recommend to download the 3.3 version. Right now this version still Beta but Blender 3.3 will be already released next week (7. Sep. 22). The "Curves > Random" menu entry was removed in 3.3.

Comment: @MartinHan All bets are off if you're using an alpha version! :^)